# Alamofire request changes method name on its own

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I am using the following code:

```
func readInfo()
{
    let customHeader : HTTPHeaders = [
                "X-AUTH-TOKEN" : accessToken
            ]
    let body : Parameters = [
                :
            ]
    Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 1000
    Alamofire.request(requestAddress, method: .get, parameters: body , encoding: JSONEncoding.default, headers: customHeader).responseJSON { 

    response in

     //utility code           

    }
}
```

It works perfect when this runs for the first time but when this is run more than once (in say less than 30 seconds), my server gives the error: `o.s.web.servlet.PageNotFound : Request method 'T' not supported`

Also I get status code 405 in Alamofire response. This is unexpected since I was sending `.get` request. Why is this happening and how should I avoid it? I am unable to understand.

Also, note that this is not a server error because the requests work as expected when run on Postman.

Comment: Why are using both `AFNetworking` & `Alamofire` together?

Comment: @Dimple, I am using Alamofire only. Check the code. AFManager is custom for handling time out.

Comment: You can use timeout for `alamofire` itself!!

Comment: @Dimple, can you help with it? How do I do the same? Will this handle the error for method name too?

Comment: Check answer below!

Comment: @Dimple, I edited the details. Looks like it is not a time out error.

Comment: Can you post `requestAddress` value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were no errors with the cache or timeout. The error was with `encoding`. I had to save it to `URLEncoding.httpBody` to make the request work as expected. I still don't understand why it worked once and not for the second time for a certain seconds. Strange case but yes this was the solution. Please leave a comment to help me and others understand why this may have happened.

Answer (score 1):

Try for Alamofire

```
 var parameters = Parameters()
 parameters = [
 //Your Params
 ]

 Alamofire.SessionManager.default.session.configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 1000
 Alamofire.request("\(url)", method: .get, parameters: parameters, encoding: JSONEncoding.default)
  .responseJSON {
   response in switch (response.result)
    {
       case .success(let data):
          // your code for success
       break

       case .failure(let error):
           print("Server_Error",error.localizedDescription)
        break
    }
```

Comment: I need to send .get , not post. And I need to send header too

Comment: Check updated answer& you can use your customisation & let me know if error still persist

Comment: it still gives the same error. Check the edited question details, the code is like yours but still it gives the same error.

Comment: then may be there should be some issue in your url & if not let me know

Comment: can you check my answer to this question once.